# Ring Theoretical Method of Solving a Math Olympiad Problem

Tags: ring-theory, contest-math

These paragraphs are from Steve Olson's book *Count Down: Six Kids Vie for Glory at the World's Toughest Math Competition*.

On page 170, the author said:

> The sixth and last problem on the Forty-second Olympiad ---
>   by tradition the hardest of all --- looked deceptively straightforward to the competitors.
>
> Let $a > b > c> d$ be positive integers and suppose that $ac +bd =(b + d + a -c)(b + d -a + c)$. Prove that $ab + cd$ is not
>   prime.

On page 174:

> Gabriel's answer to problem six demonstrated his power as a
>   mathematician. "Gabe's solution was overkill," says Stankova,
>   "but he solved the problem the way a mathematician would solve it." In his solution he used a mathematical idea called a ring --- a set of mathematical objects, any two of which can be added or multiplied to yield another member of the set.

**Edit**
On page 210:

> Gabriel's use of imaginary numbers in problem six was directly linked to the famous equation $e^{\pi i} = -1$. The number omega ($\omega$)
>   is defined as $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$. So $\omega^2 = e^{2\pi i/3}\times e^{2\pi i/3}=e^{2\pi i/3+2\pi i/3}=e^{4\pi i/3}$ (because the exponents of $e$ can be added together when the two numbers are multiplied). By the same token, $\omega^3 =e^{6\pi i/3}=e^{2\pi i}=e^{\pi i}\times e^{\pi i}= -1 \times -1 = 1$.
>   Thus the set of numbers $1, -1, \omega, -\omega, \omega^2$, and $-w^2$ are related in a particular way. If you multiply any two of them together, you get another member of the set. Gabriel used the powerful properties of this group to crack problem six.

The original problem: https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx (2001)

**My Question:** How did he solve the problem in a ring theoretical method?

Comment: The way that text is written is ... cringeworthy at best. Honestly, with problems like these, any methods that use ring properties can also be solved with the equivalent integer manipulations. I don't know what the author is getting at.

Comment: Maybe just working with $(a+c)(b+d)\pmod {ab+cd}$?  I didn't work it out.

Comment: Also $(a-c)(b-d)$ might be important, because if $ab+cd$ is assumed to be prime, it is associate to the other product I mentioned in the quotient ring.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to quote a paragraph. I have made it. It seems to use group theory.

Comment: Af first glance, it seems to hint at employing the ring of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer). And a quick glance at an [AoPS solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_6) shows (unmotivated) integer calculations involving obvious Eisenstein integer norms, so it should be straightforward to reformulate that more naturally in Eisenstein arithmetic. Likely that is the "ring theoretic" solution implied in the book.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gabriel's original solution. 
Posted with the permission of the author.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]